# CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this function

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE name = 'MydB') THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'db already created';
   ELSE
                         CREATE DATABASE MydB;
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

However when this runs I get the error:

```
CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function
```

can anyone recommend a good way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run `CREATE DATABASE` inside a transaction, so you cannot run it in a function.

Run it without using the `DO` statement, and if you get an error with SQLSTATE 42P04, ignore it – it means that the database already exists.